# How to replace with the new tag values in the table?

Tags: django, python-2.7

I have a Event table and a Tags table:

```
tags = Tags.objects.filter(event_id=id).values_list('name')
```

gives me list of existing values

```
oldlist = {"tags":"['tag1', 'tag4', 'tag3']"}
```

I have new list

```
newlist = {"tags":"['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3']"}
```

I have tables as:

```
Table: Event
    id, title, content
Table: Tags
    id event_id, name
```

while user is updating an event he can update the tags also, how to store these new tags and replace them with the previous once?

```
tagobj = Tags.objects.filter(event_id = id)
if len(tags) > 0:
  for i in range(len(tags)):
    tagsobj = tagobj.update(name = tags[i], event_id = key)
```

the above code is updating but only storing the last value in the table. I need to update the values with the new ones.

The list can contain any number of values.I need to replace the new list with the existing ones in the database.

Simply I just want to update the new tags with the oldones.How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the following lines:

```
for i in range(len(tags)):
    tagsobj = tagobj.update(name = tags[i], event_id = key)
```

You are calling update on a QuerySet `tagobj`, which will update all tags in the QuerySet.  So all your tags will have the value of the last tag.

If I understand your question correctly, it should work if you update each individual tag.

```
i = 0
for tag_item in tagobj:
    tag_item.update(name=tags[i], event_id=key)
    i +=1
```

Comment: for i in range(len(tags)):
    for tag_item in tagobj:
        tag_item.update(name=tags[i], event_id=key)

also updated every value in the tags table. I need to update each value with the new list and store them in the table.

Comment: I'll update the question.  Basically, you can't have two for loops here.  You need to create your own counter for tags.